# TextView attribute in android for displaying intergers?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == button1){
            counter++;
            textView2.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            textView2.setText(counter);
        }

    }
```

I have tried to create a program that counts the number of clicks on a button, but for some reason it is not displaying it. Here is my textview component.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

I can't seem to find an attribute for display the number of clicks. Is this because it interprets it as an interger instead of a string?

Comment: Try removing `textView2.setText(counter)`; This method accepts only an  integer **resource** (as in `R.string.someValue`) . Also, make sure that the TextView is actually displayed, in case the layout is not proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

This takes your Integer and converts it to its String value, and sets it to your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

try casting your counter variable to string variable and then try assigning it to button text as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == button1){
            counter++;
            String s=counter.toString();
            textView2.setText(S);
        }

    }
```

what your code might be doing as of what you have posted you are trying to pass an integer which is creating problem here..